# Match a string with getDate and if matches perform click action

Tags: javascript, selenium

-Hey guys, posting for the first time but been lurking for a long time.

```
-Using selenium+javascript+mocha+chai
```

I have a date picker which contains multiple button,`divs`  and `span` that holds the date number which i need to select but only if it matches with current day, so if element `div[string() = "1"] == getDate()` then click , but i am not sure how to write this, i tried with for and if but it wont work inside my `"it"`, let me know if you need more information

Comment: Could you add the code that you have already tried? And how you HTML looks like?

Comment: <span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-weight: 400; position: relative;">30</span>  here 30 is the element i need to click on the page, and this is how i currently select the date and click it inside the time picker.
      browser.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="date__policy_start_date__picker"]')).click()
      browser.findElement(By.xpath('//span[string()="30"]')).click(); but this is a temporary solution since i need to change the date every-time before i run the test, and i need to pick the current day

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it creating  const date = new Date();
and then using browser.findElement(By.xpath(`//span[string()=${date.getDate()}]`)).click();